# Can clone (svn-imported) Git repository locally but not remotely

Tags: git, clone

The short version: I've imported a Subversion repository, with history, to Git. I think I've done it correctly — there are a few pretty good guides available on the subject — and I am able to, at least on the same machine as I've cloned a bare copy as my to-be-master-repository, clone another local copy. So that makes me think I've at least got the repo set up mostly correctly: I can `git clone path/to/repo.git` and get a working copy with all the files, commit logs, etc.

That's all on my server (a Dreamhost VPS, actually), which is used to host a number of domains, pages, etc.

What I *can't* seem to do is clone to my local machine. When I try to do so, using `git clone https://example.com/path/to/repo.git` or `git clone ssh://user@example.com/path/to/repo.git`, I get: `fatal: repository 'https://example.com/path/to/repo.git' not found` or `fatal: '/path/to/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository`.

I *can* go directly, in a browser, to `https://example.com/path/to/repo.git` and see the contents of `repo.git` there in the browser, and I'm able to ssh in without a problem, so I can(?) rule out certain configuration issues.

But again, it works just fine locally (on the same server).

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you ssh into the machine?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned I can ssh in without a problem, independently. It's as a URL method for `git clone` that it doesn't work.